# How to get current date in year type

Tags: javascript

I want to know how do I can get current year and month and day, but in year format in javascript

example:

when the date is 2016/6/15, the format will be 2016.5 (year's center)

Comment: `2016.50`? What is it?

Comment: it's an example for what i want

Comment: What is it? How did you get it?

Comment: when the date is 2016/6/15, the format will be 2016.5 (year's center)

Comment: you can look [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date) and you generate a formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function getNumberOfDaysPast(date) {
  var currentMonth = date.getMonth();

  var total = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < currentMonth; i++) {
    var month = new Date(date.getFullYear(), i, 0);

    total += month.getDate();

  }


  total += date.getDate();


  return total;
}

function dayPercent(date) {
  if (date.getFullYear() % 4 == 0 && date.getFullYear % 100 != 0) {
    return Math.floor((getNumberOfDaysPast(date) / 366) * 100)
  } else {
    return Math.floor((getNumberOfDaysPast(date) / 365) * 100)
  }
}


date = new Date("2016-12-31");

console.log(dayPercent(date))


date = new Date();

console.log(dayPercent(date));

console.log(date.getFullYear() + '.' + dayPercent(date))
```

*UPDATE*

taking leap years into account, we need add a day in only on the 4th year that is not the 100th year

http://www.timeanddate.com/date/leapyear.html

> Exactly Which Years Are Leap Years?
>   We add a Leap Day on February 29, almost every four years. The leap day is an extra, or intercalary, day and we add it to the shortest month of the year, February.
>   In the Gregorian calendar three criteria must be taken into account to identify leap years:
>   The year can be evenly divided by 4;
>   If the year can be evenly divided by 100, it is NOT a leap year, unless;
>   The year is also evenly divisible by 400. Then it is a leap year.
>   This means that in the Gregorian calendar, the years 2000 and 2400 are leap years, while 1800, 1900, 2100, 2200, 2300 and 2500 are NOT leap years.

Comment: The OP wants the year in decimal format, not the date formatted as year.month.day.

Comment: lol didnt get that :/

Comment: thank you but I want the day and month together, SO i just want year. (2016.5...)

Comment: @WalksAway Sorry I was kidding. So the OP gives a date. Out of the date in the 365 days, which part? 50% or 25%? If 50% it is 2016.5 and if 25% it's 2016.25!

Comment: yeah i got that now

Comment: LoL. Ha ha... Why such a username?

Comment: so i could walk away :P

Comment: is there an answer.. : (

Comment: i updated my answer this will help i hope... , unless i got it wrong again

Comment: is that what you were going for?

Comment: it looks like the correct answer. thank you.

Comment: I guess it's no big deal that it doesn't deal with leap years